# SQL Cumulative Count with BigQuery for active

Tags: sql, date, group-by, google-bigquery, bucket

I would like to know how to the rows date falls into once truncated into week. Current data is

| Ad Name | Launch Date | Last Seen |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ad 1 | 9 Dec, 2021 | 16 Dec, 2021 |
| Ad 2 | 1 Dec, 2021 | 9 Dec, 2021 |
| Ad 3 | 1 Dec, 2021 | 31 Dec, 2021 |

Desired output would be, imaginging that December has 4 weeks. The dates provided are examples only, they would be automatically generated by the SQL function date_trunc

| Week | Active Ads |
| --- | --- |
| Dec Date 1-7 | 2 |
| Dec Date 7-14 | 3 |
| Dec Date 14-21 | 2 |
| Dec Date 21-30 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select 
  date_trunc(seen_day, week) week_start,
  last_day(seen_day, week) week_end,
  count(distinct ad_name) Active_Ads
from your_table, 
unnest(generate_date_array(
  parse_date('%d %B, %Y', launch_date), 
  parse_date('%d %B, %Y', last_seen)
)) seen_day
group by 1, 2
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]